# Indoor Navigation Mapping with Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, svg, mapping, indoor-positioning-system

I am working on **Indoor Navigation** App using **Cordova** (HTML,CSS,JS), It will detect the Position of the user automatically and target him to his destination.
  I have already the building mapp as jpeg and i want to intergrate it [for example](http://intoomobile.com/img/iphone-sandwich.png).
 Should i draw it with svg and manipulate it with JS or is there any oppen source tools that can i use it?I would appreciate any suggestions.